# Regular Expression with delimiters and length

Tags: regex

I have a tricky regular expression I need to implement and I'm not a great RegEx guy.

The rules are:

2 alphanumeric characters followed by a `.` or a `-` followed by 2 alphanumeric characters.

It cannot be empty and it cannot have only one pair (i.e. `01`)  The string can be up to 10 sets of 2 alpha numerics.   i.e.,  `01.02.03.04.05.06.10`  and the delimiter, once selected, cannot change.  And the expression cannot end with a delimiter

Examples are:

Valid:

```
a1.02.b3.00
01-02-aa-04
01.02
aa.bb
ac.21
```

Invalid:

```
aa.01-02
123.2.10
01
a1.
```

Ideas?

Comment: 1. What flavor of regex? 2. Why must it be done with a regex?

Comment: @ All...I'm using the [RegularExpression()] modifier for a property on an MVC3 Model object.  It's great to user because the validation is applied anywhere that property is used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EY, GUYS!?

why make things more complicated than they have to be?

```
^[a-z0-9]{2}([.-])([a-z0-9]{2}\1){0,8}[a-z0-9]{2}$
```

Depending on where you are using this regular expression you have a few options regarding making it match uppercase characters aswell.

---

If you are writing the regexp as `/regular-expression/`:  Use `/i` as modifier (case-insensitive match).

If you are using regular expressions under .NET (as you have noted) you use the `IgnoreCase` option.

---

**Explanation of the differents parts in this regex**

- `^[a-z0-9]{2}` the string must start with two characters that matches `\w` (ie. [a-z0-9A-Z])
- `([.-])` the next character must be either a dot or a hyphen, from now on `\1` will contain this value
- `([a-z0-9]{2}\1){0,8}` we want zero to 8 pairs of *2 * alpha numeric chars* + *the first delimiter used*.
- `[a-z0-9]{2}` the string must end with two alpha numeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
^[[:alnum:]]{2}([-.])[[:alnum:]]{2}(?:\1[[:alnum:]]{2}){0,8}$
```

You need the anchors on both ends to make it match the whole string.  Using `[[:alnum:]]` matches all alphanumerics, based on locale.  If you want only the ones we consider in English, regardless of locale, you would want to use `[A-Za-z0-9]` in each case instead.

The trickiest part is the backreference, `\1`, which makes sure that you always use the same delimiter---it refers to the capturing parentheses in `([-.])`.  Thus, when you have 0-8 more repetitions of delimiter followed by 2 alphanumerics, the delimiter is always the same.

I tried this in Perl, and it passes a few test strings that I threw at it.  Your mileage might vary if you're using a different language/library.

Comment: @david...I tried 01.01.01 and it didn't pass.  I'm using C#.Net

Comment: This passes in Perl.  Maybe .net doesn't support Perl's character classes?  Did you try replacing `[[:alnum:]]` with `[A-Za-z0-9]` in all the cases?

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like:

```
[a-z0-9]{2}\([.][a-z0-9]{2}\){1,9}|[a-z0-9]{2}\([-][a-z0-9]{2}\){1,9}
```

{2} means exactly 2

{1,9} means at least one, and up to 9

\(something\) is a grouping

a|b means match either a or b

Comment: @smendola...thanks for the explanatino of the above definitions. Nice!  Tha was really helpful for my understanding of RegEx

Comment: @smendola the [.] will not match any element? but only the '.' character?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly...

```
([\p{L}0-9]{2})(\.|-)([\p{L}0-9]{2})
```

This handles Unicode letters too, but I'm not sure that it is correct for your needs as your first two lines in the "Valid" set contain items that are <2 alpha-num><.><2 alpha-num><.><2 alpha-num><.><2 alpha-num> and not the format that you mention in the question where you are looking for <2 alpha-num><.><2 alpha-num>

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This may work:

`^[\w\d][\w\d](?:([.-])[\w\d][\w\d])(?:\1[\w\d][\w\d]){,8}`